# Understanding the proof for a sequence to be Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let {$S_n$} be a sequence of real numbers, and for each n in set of positive integers ,

let $S_n = a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n$

$t_n =|a_1|+|a_2|+|a_3|+|a_4|+...|a_n|$.

Prove that {$t_n$} is a cauchy sequence then so is {$S_n$}.

The proof goes like:-

{$t_n$} is a Cauchy seq.

implies that

for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a positive integer N such that
$n>m\ge N$ implies that $|t_n-t_m|< \epsilon$.

implies that

for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $n>m \ge N$ implies that

$| |a_m|+ |a_{m+1}|+ ...+|a_n| | < \epsilon$

[From where these terms come from? How are these terms obtained? I want some steps to clarify how these terms come and an example will probably help.]

Comment: Those terms are just using the definition of $t_n$. For example, take $t_2 = |a_1| + |a_2|$, and $t_5$ = $|a_1| + |a_2| + |a_3| + |a_4| + |a_5|$. Then $|t_5 - t_2|  = | ~|a_3| + |a_4| + |a_5|$

Comment: Sorry but if we take n=5 and m=2 then the terms are not you have mentioned @stochasticboy321

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(s_n)$ be the sequence of partial sums of the infinite series $\sum a_n$ associated to the sequence $(a_n)$. That is, 
\begin{align*}
s_1 & =a_1 \\
s_2 & = a_1 + a_2 \\
\vdots & = \cdots \\
s_n & = a_1 + \cdots + a_n \\
\vdots &
\end{align*}
$(t_n)$ is the sequence of partial sum of the series $\sum |a_n|$.

Now, let $(t_n)$ be Cauchy. Then for any $ \epsilon >0$ we can find an integer $N=N(\epsilon)$, that is, dependent on $\epsilon $ , so that, for all $n,m \geq N$, we have that ($m>n$):
\begin{align*}
 |t_m - t_n|&= \left||a_1|+...+ |a_m| - (|a_1|+...+|a_n|) \right| \\
& = \left||a_{n+1}| +...+|a_m|\right| < \epsilon
\end{align*}

Now, by the triangle inequality, it holds that:
$$ \left| a_{n+1} + ... + a_m \right| \leq \left||a_{n+1}| +...+|a_m|\right|.$$

Thus, our result follows immediately by choosing for $(s_n)$ the same  $N(\epsilon)$ previously chosen for $(t_n)$.

What we have shown is that absolute convergence implies convergence.